# Is there any fix for divs inside of label

Tags: html, css, label

I just spent a long time making a css animation with `div`s inside a `label` (with the press of the label initiating the animation), just to realize that having `div`s inside a `label` is incorrect.
Does anyone know a quick fix for this?
This is the HTML in question:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="spinner" />
  <label for="spinner" id="burger">
  <div id="burger-div">
    <div class="spinner diagonal part-1"></div>
    <div class="spinner horizontal"></div>
    <div class="spinner diagonal part-2"></div>
    </div>
  </label>
```

The css that animates it, in case it is relevant:

```
#spinner[type=checkbox]:checked~#burger .horizontal {
    opacity: 0;
}
#spinner[type=checkbox]:checked~#burger .diagonal.part-1 {
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#spinner[type=checkbox]:checked~#burger .diagonal.part-2 {
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    margin-top: -16px;
}
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Basically I need a way to make clicking the divs activate the checkbox, without the divs being inside a label?

Comment: Uhm, <span>s with display:block instead of <div>s?

Comment: Could it be? Ill try!

Comment: Seems like i'll have to adjust the css a bit, but it works! Thank you.

Comment: Actually, no adjustments beyond display:block were needed. I just forgot to change the closing tags to /span lol. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The valid HTML would be to use a `<span>` instead of a `<div>`. Reason is that `label` represents a text construct and `div` represents a container object.